# While loop in Bash not running

Tags: bash, while-loop

I'm pretty new with Bash scripting and am having trouble getting my 'while' loop to run. When I echo `keywords`, a whole list of words prints and then when I echo `length`, it prints `124`. I believe I'm using the while loop and condition correctly, so I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any thoughts?

```
keywords=$1
length=${#keywords}

echo "$keywords"
echo "$length"

if [ -z "$keywords" ]; then
    while [ $length -gt 100 ]; do
        echo "$keywords"
        echo "$length"

        keywords="${keywords%,*}"
        length=${#keywords}
    done
fi

echo $keywords
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
[ -z "$keywords" ]
```

`-z` is true if its argument is an empty string. Something of length 124 is definitely far from empty. You probably meant `-n`.

Next time, please also include the input in the question so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: The entire `if` statement is unnecessary; if the string is empty, `[ $length -gt 100 ]` will fail and the loop will just be skipped.

Comment: I must have misread the documentation and had the empty string flag backwards. Thank you!